# Euro symbol not displayed properly from a properties file

Tags: java, character-encoding, properties-file

I am reading a properties file which contains € euro symbol. When it prints on the screen which looks totally different. I compared the string from props file and by declaring another string with same text using equals method it is false.

properties file:

your purchase order is €

string text="your purchase order is €";

on comparing the above strings it fails.

```
************************
public String getProperty(String arg0) {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        InputStream input = null;

        
            try {
                input = new FileInputStream("C:/text.properties");
                
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                
                prop.load(input);
        
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    
        return prop.getProperty(arg0);

    }
```

Comment: how is it displayed?

Comment: Where do you output it ? IDE console ? Shell ?

Comment: Can you please provide the properties file content as well so that we can look and see?

Answer (score 7):

The `Properties.load` method that takes an `InputStream` assumes that the file is saved in the `ISO-8859-1` character encoding, which cannot represent the euro symbol directly.  If the file is really in a different encoding such as UTF-8 then you should use the `load` method that takes a `Reader` instead, and use an `InputStreamReader` to specify the correct encoding.

Alternatively, `Properties` files support Unicode escape sequences, so you can represent the euro sign as `\u20ac` in the file and it will be decoded into a real `€` character when the file is loaded.

Aside from this there are a number of flaws in your current code, most importantly that you need to ensure the input stream is properly closed after you have loaded the properties from it.  The easiest way to do this is the "try with resources" syntax

```
try(InputStream in = new FileInputStream("C:/text.properties");
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8")) {
  prop.load(reader);
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And it seems wasteful to re-load the properties file every single time you request a value from it, you might consider loading it just once (either up front or the first time it is requested) and cacheing the `Properties` object for later use.

Comment: For £ it is \u00A3.